# Add parentheses to cross references

Tags: vba, ms-word

I'd like to add parentheses to all cross references in my Word document. I've created a macro that defines the style of the text, but I'd like this macro to also add "(" before and ")" after every cross reference automatically.

I've tried to do this in find and replace but can't seem to find a way.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please take a moment to read in the site's [help] about how to effectively ask questions on Stack Overflow. A question should contain *complete* relevant information, including the code you already have as a starting point. You can use the [edit] link under the question to add more information.

Comment: You need to iterate the fields collection and test each field for it being a a reference type.

Comment: When you find a field of referernce type you also need to check the code of the field because not all reference fields are cross references. Spacifically for cross references you need to check if the code text contains the string "_Ref"

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a simple Find/Replace! Press Alt-F9, then use:

```
Find = ^d REF
Replace = (^&)
```

and press Alt-F9 again when you're done.

Comment: This works brilliantly - thank you. The issue I encounter with this solution however is that each time I run the macro, it adds parentheses each time, so I end up with some cross references with multiple brackets either side. 

Is there a way to find and replace cross references with more than one set of parentheses?

Comment: Perhaps you should leave that process until you've completed your other editing. Alternatively, you could select the range you want to process (i.e. one that doesn't already have the parentheses) before running the Find/Replace. If neither of those options suits, you'll need two extra Find/Replace, to replace paired opening/closing parentheses with single opening/closing parentheses.